# Meteor - missing username Meteor.users.findOne(); or Meteor.users();

Tags: javascript, meteor

Upon submit of a post, the current user does not seem to be recognised and username appears as blank. The submit html has `{{author}}` to display the user who wrote the post.

Heres the results when I type the following in the console:

1)`user.username`

=> result `user` is undefined.

2)`Meteor.users.find();`

=> `LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId: undefined, matcher: Minimongo.Matcher, skip: undefined…}`

3) `Meteor.users.findOne();`

=> `Object {_id: "P3ocCTTdvi2o3JApf", profile: Object}`

compared to the working version (Note my version is missing username)

=> `Object {_id: "XHXPebzjg5LM5tNAu", profile: Object, username: "Bruno"}`

In post.js collection (in the lib folder - shared with both client and server), I have:

```
Meteor.methods({
  postInsert: function(postAttributes) {
    check(this.userId, String);           //check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(postAttributes, {
      title: String,
      message: String
    });
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var post = _.extend(postAttributes, {
      userId: user._id, 
      author: user.username
    });
    var postId = Posts.insert(post);
    return {_id: postId};
  },
```

There are also no other references to `author` in the Discover Meteor tutorial, and it worked. However mine doesnt work. This problem seems to have started after I added UserAccounts package. Or perhaps a folder location issue?

**Update [11 May 2015]**

I realised that when using the original ui-accounts that came with Meteor, it has the `username` field because the sign up link that came with `{{> login}}` uses username + password. Theres no email address involved.

UserAccounts on the other hand doesnt have this username field. Its either email/pw or social login. So perhaps someone guide me on how to have username (either as separate field or derived from email) from email/pw and social network button login/signin as a start? Then Ill try to fiddle from there.

**code for UserAccounts**

**router.js**

```
//Iron router plugin to ensure user is signed in
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('ensureSignedIn', {
  template: 'atTemplate',     //template shown if user is not signed in
  layoutTemplate: 'atLayout'  //template for login, registration, etc
});

Router.plugin('ensureSignedIn', { //Don't require user logged in for these routes
  except: ['login', 'register']   //can use only: too 
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {  //login
  name: 'login',
  path: '/login',
  template: 'atTemplate',
  layoutTemplate: 'atLayout',
  redirect: '/'
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {  //registration
  name: 'register',
  path: '/register',
  template: 'atTemplate',
  layoutTemplate: 'atLayout',
  redirect: '/'
});
```

**and under config.js (server side)**

Comment: Rather than including images, please try to include code (and perhaps comments for the responses). When you do `{{expr}}` directly in the console, the curly braces fail object literal interpretation so become code blocks instead. Meaning it's almost exactly the same as just doing `expr`. i.e. the `author` you tried to access in the _Console_ was using vanilla _JavaScript_ and not meteor.

Comment: @PaulS. My bad. Let me remove the part on `{{expr}}`. As for code, as the devtool is not throwing up errors, Im not sure which part of the code to consider pasting. I did a search on all parts that had `{{author}}` or `user` and hence pasted only the part within collections. Would you have suggestions on where to start looking or other tools to use etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Useraccounts doc, Try this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.methods({
        "userExists": function(username){
            return !!Meteor.users.findOne({username: username});
        },
    });
}

AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'username',
    type: 'text',
    required: true,
    func: function(value){
        if (Meteor.isClient) {
            console.log("Validating username...");
            var self = this;
            Meteor.call("userExists", value, function(err, userExists){
                if (!userExists)
                    self.setSuccess();
                else
                    self.setError(userExists);
                self.setValidating(false);
            });
            return;
        }
        // Server
        return Meteor.call("userExists", value);
    },
});
```

This will add the username field to your login/register forms and check for username conflicts when registering new users.

The top part is server code the bottom part is common code, so you could place this whole snippet in project/lib/ folder, or place the method with the rest of your methods, depending on how your structuring your project.

Use the following to have the username field show up first instead of last on the register form:

```
var pwd = AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');
AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');
AccountsTemplates.addFields([
  {
    _id: "username",
    type: "text",
    displayName: "username",
    required: true,
    func: function(value){
      if (Meteor.isClient) {
        console.log("Validating username...");
        var self = this;
        Meteor.call("userExists", value, function(err, userExists){
          if (!userExists)
            self.setSuccess();
          else
            self.setError(userExists);
          self.setValidating(false);
        });
        return;
      }
      // Server
      return Meteor.call("userExists", value);
    },
    minLength: 5,
  },
  {
    _id: 'email',
    type: 'email',
    required: true,
    displayName: "email",
    re: /.+@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/,
    errStr: 'Invalid email',
  },
  pwd
]);
```

https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.`s to access properties of objects, not spaces

```
Meteor.users.findOne
```

Comment: Sorry for the error, you are right in the `.` placement, amended my post as above. Any suggestions where I should look for the problem in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You provided very little information to spot your problem.
This said, how are you letting your users in?

Be aware that OAuth registrations do not provide a `username` field on the created user object, as well as password registration based on email address only. In these cases `user.username` would be `undefined`.

I'd suggest to make sure all your users get a `profile.username` (possibly exploiting some `Accounts.onLogin` hook or some profile page where to force the user to select a username.

After this you would extend your post metadata setting `author: user.profile.username`

Comment: I'm using UserAccounts :) . Previously,  ui-accounts would hook up directly. Does it mean UserAccounts requires manual hook up?

Comment: Well, useraccounts does nothing more than what `Accounts` package provides. It simply calls `Accounts.loginWith<Sevice>` and similar, that's it.

I'm not sure `accounts-ui` adds more _features_ to the base package: I'd say no!

Comment: @splendiido the ui-accounts version did not require `Accounts.loginWith<Service>` , or any `profile.username` and the login worked fine. So im not sure what needs to be inserted for UserAccounts.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed description about what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @splendido - im trying to implement `UserAccounts`. I realised that I might have missed out username field which explains why original ui-accounts version had `username` field while mine using `UserAccounts` doesnt. I need to understand how to include that field in the login/ signup or any ways to troubleshoot the problems above. Theres no other error messages so I myself am not sure what else to write here

Comment: Have you read the official Guide, and in particular this https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#login-with-username-or-email?